# Do MySQL (5.7) indexes take a while to update after many UPDATE / INSERT operations?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, mysql-5.7, database-indexes

I'm experiencing a similar "bug" to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94068, where an index I've created on my generated columns doesn't seem to be effective after I run many `INSERT/UPDATE` operations on my table. But if I drop and recreate the index, my queries are lightning fast. I'm not sure if, given enough time, the originally created index would "update" itself and become performant again on its own.

The bug author notes that they observe this behavior not only for an index on a generated column but also when writing actual columns with a trigger. I don't quite understand the MySQL developer's explanation as to why it's expected behavior, as dropping and recreating the index improves the performance drastically... is that expected??

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, and how they've dealt with it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer:

As far as a program can tell, indexes, whether `UNIQUE` or not, are "immediately" updated.

On an `INSERT`, all unique keys must be checked for "duplicate key" *before* the `INSERT` completes (or fails due to dup key).  Non-unique key updates put in the "change buffer" for eventual flushing to disk.  However, any use of the index also checks in the change buffer, so you are effectively oblivious of the existence of the change buffer.

If the question is about the changing of the `EXPLAIN` plan over time, as the bug report seems to talk about, that is a different matter.  You need to rephrase your Question with that in mind.

Recreating the index is a heavy operation.  Next time, do `ANALYZE TABLE`.  This refreshes the statistics for all the indexes on the table.  Here is what you *might* be experiencing:

1. Query is nicely using an index.
2. You add lots of new rows, thereby making the statistics not quite right anymore.
3. Since each query decides independently which index to use, or even whether to use any index, your query may 'suddenly' choose to use an index that it was not being used before or vice versa.
4. `ANALYZE TABLE` actively refreshes the statistics.
5. Now your query *may* go back to the previous way of using (or not) the desired index.

It would be better to talk about a specific query and its `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There may be things we can do to speed up the query and/or prevent the problem that I am hypothecating.